# Is OH the same as O-H?

Tags: bond

When 2-hydroxylpropanitrite undergoes hydrolysis by H20, it will become 2-hydroxylpropanoic acid. In the structural formula, I wrote the O-H that are connected to the carbon with double bond as OH. Is it still the same thing or it is incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

$\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{-O-H}$ are the same.

The single bond between oxygen and hydrogen is implied in the first representation and this representation is the most commonly used because of it's brevity.